# SwiftUI same NavigationView for all views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation

I have a `NavigationView` component in my iOS app that's built with `SwiftUI`.

I want to have the exact same navigation bar for all views in my app. all the views are reachable throught the `NavigationView`, so i basically want to replace the current viewed view every time a navigation link is clicked (in my case, replacing `MainView` with any other view).

is it possible or am i missing something about the way navigation is being managed in Swift?

**here's my ContentView.swift:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var state = AppState()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // Gestures
        let closeMenuDrag = DragGesture()
            .onEnded {
                if (self.state.isMenuOpen && $0.translation.width < -100) {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.state.isMenuOpen = false
                    }
                }
            }
        
        // UI
        return NavigationView {
            GeometryReader {  geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    
                    // Navigation
                    if (self.state.isMenuOpen) {
                        SidebarMenuView()
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2.2)
                            .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                    }
                    
                    // Main
                    MainView()
                        .frame(
                            width: geometry.size.width,
                            height: geometry.size.height

                        )
                        .disabled(self.state.isMenuOpen)
                
                }
                .gesture(closeMenuDrag)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: (
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.state.isMenuOpen = !self.state.isMenuOpen
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                }
            ))
        }.onAppear {
            // Make API call here
            Repository().getCurrentWeather { (CurrentWeatherDataModel) in
                    self.state.currentWeatherData = CurrentWeatherDataModel
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The navigation sidebar:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SidebarMenuView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            Spacer()
                .frame(maxHeight: 80)
            
            SidebarHeader()
                .padding(50)
                .background(Color(.systemTeal))
            
            // Menu Items
            ForEach(SideMenuViewModel.allCases, id: \.self) { option in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text(option.destination),
                    label: {
                        SideMenuOptionView(viewModel: option)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    })
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            alignment: .leading
        )
        .background(Color(.white))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}
```

Comment: So you don't want the back Button ?

Comment: @S_dnomseD Yes that's also a way to say it

Comment: @S_dnomseD or rather that i don't want the back button, instead i want to maintain the hamburger button that leads to the navigation menu

Comment: So you want hamburger menu to be on every view you navigate?

Comment: @TusharSharma yes, the question is is that possible without code repitition